# How do I set the vsync option with the radeon driver?

Tags: 11.10, ati, radeon

ok am very new to linux so am finding quite a few stumbling blocks with it but most of the help i can find online.

i have a sempron with an older ati gfx card that requires me to use the radeon driver and not the offical ATI ones.

the problem i am encountering is image tearing while watching video's and i've tried to look into the problem online and all i can come up with is websites saying put the option of Vsync in the xorg.conf file. But as you well know, xorg.conf is not used any more (as i understand).

Also i am suffering from the drivers/linux/whatever not picking up the correct EDID data from the monitor so lack correct screen resolutions. cvt and xrandr are not picking up the correct res/pixel clocks as the screen garbles but i guess i can just get the correct pixel clocks via a windows box and powerstrip.

I am mainly concerned with fixing the VSync problem as watching video is damned horrible, so any input you could give me with this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can still use an Xorg.conf. By default it is not used anymore but you can create one for manual configuration.

Invoke

```
sudo Xorg -configure
```

to create an initial Xorg.conf. This one you can edit to make special changes as required.

Comment: thanks for that i'll give it a go tonight n see what i can come up with :D

Answer (score 0):

I had screen tearing issues also. Vsync didn't help since the problem was with OpenGL. Solved the problem by switching to Lubuntu, which uses OpenBox instead of OpenGL.

For more info, see [my post](https://askubuntu.com/a/647350/171608) in this this thread: Have tearing (no Vsync) in movies (Nvidia proprietary driver)