# 20-nvidia.conf in xorg.conf.d doesnt exist

Tags: drivers, nvidia, xorg

I'm new to GNU/Linux, running xubuntu 15.10 with a GTX 570 graphics card, and am trying to prevent screen tearing in scrolling web pages, videos, and steam games. I get no screen tearing with the PPA version of the nvidia 355.11 drivers, but it requires me to enter the following in the terminal after every boot and during a steam game.

```
 nvidia-settings --assign CurrentMetaMode="nvidia-auto-select +0+0 { ForceFullCompositionPipeline = On }"
```

It seems in order to make the change permanent, I need to add a line to the `xorg.conf` file (which seems to be deprecated) or the `20-nvidia.conf` file in `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/` but neither files exist. In my `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/` directory there are only the following files:

```
10-evdev.conf         11-evdev-trackpoint.conf  50-wacom.conf
10-quirks.conf        50-synaptics.conf         51-synaptics-quirks.conf
11-evdev-quirks.conf  50-vmmouse.conf           glamoregl.conf
```

and none of them have a `screen` section, or `serverlayout` section. I've tried several workarounds but they either don't fix the tearing or cause lightdm to not start at all. I've made a `xorg.conf` file with `sudo X :1 -configure` and placed it in the `/etc/X11/` directory then added in the following:

```
Section "Screen"
Option  "metamodes" "nvidia-auto-select +0+0 { ForceFullCompositionPipeline = On }"
EndSection
```

and tried a shell script in `/etc/profile.d/` to run the first terminal command I mentioned earlier. It either doesn't stop the tearing and I have to change the nvidia setting in the terminal to fix it like usual, or lightdm just doesn't display anything and I have to recover through grub loader. If I save the configuration settings in nvidia x server settings it creates a file `.nvidia-settings-rc` but nowhere in the file can I see it mentioning the current metamode.

Some of this information used to get me where I am seems outdated, but I can't find `20-nvidia.conf` or some kind of equivalent on my drive.

[Giovanni Toraldo's answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/456355/have-tearing-no-vsync-in-movies-nvidia-proprietary-driver) will fix my screen tearing but the permanent solution isn't applicable.

- [`xorg.conf` manual](http://www.x.org/archive/X11R7.7/doc/man/man5/xorg.conf.5.xhtml)
- [PPA drivers](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2015/08/ubuntu-nvidia-graphics-drivers-ppa-is-ready-for-action)

Answer (score 0):

I had success generating a new `xorg.conf` simply with `nvidia-xconfig` in the terminal. Added in the aforementioned `"metamodes"` option, moved and renamed `xorg.conf` to `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-nvidia.conf` and haven't seen screen tearing since.

[This section](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/NVIDIA#Avoid_tearing_with_GeForce_500.2F600.2F700.2F900_series_cards) on the ArchWiki was most useful