# How to turn vsync on or reduce screen tearing

Tags: 18.04, drivers, nvidia, graphics

I tried a few methods on the web. I have updated my Ubuntu 18.04 software by using Software Updater. I'm currently using Nvidia proprietary software.

Specs:

- GPU: Nvidia GTX 1050MTi
- CPU: i5 8300H
- display: 60Hz

I want to have a tear-free experience like in Windows 10. Also turning vsync on would probably help reduce the fan load. For some reason the fans are noisy and go brrrrrr when using Ubuntu, unlike when using Windows 10.

Now when I try to boot up the OS gets stuck at a black screen here.

[image]

Comment: In the Nvidia server Settings, under the OpenGL Settings, did you check off the Sync to VBlank?

Comment: try https://askubuntu.com/questions/456355/have-tearing-no-vsync-in-movies-nvidia-proprietary-driver Do proper research

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Have tearing (no Vsync) in movies (Nvidia proprietary driver)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/456355/have-tearing-no-vsync-in-movies-nvidia-proprietary-driver)

Comment: I tried this method https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=YvD9JvEna8o , now my ubuntu doesn't boot up.

Comment: now when I try to boot up , the OS gets stuck here: http://imgur.com/a/YluT4nn  , any way to get out of here?