# Tried to add a command to my startup list, now it gets stuck when trying to boot up

Tags: boot, nvidia, startup, startup-applications, startupmanager

I was working on another ubuntu
[problem](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=YvD9JvEna8o) , which required me to add a command to my startup list. Now, when I try to boot up, my OS gets stuck at this [screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/72g3a.jpg). Any way to fix this?
I added a command relating to nvidia drivers. [This](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1271972/how-to-turn-vsync-on-or-how-to-reduce-screen-tearing-in-ubuntu) is the problem which I was working on.

Edit:

Ubuntu version: 18.04

Comment: What do you mean by startup list, crontab, rcon? As well as, what ubuntu version, and what are you trying to do on startup? Can you start the OS at all?

Comment: ubuntu version: 18.04, I can start it, but it gets stuck on the aforementioned screen. I added a command modifying some nvidia property to the list of startup programs. I don't know what is crontab or rcon unfortunately. I searched for startup on ubuntu, a program came up, I added it there.

Comment: I am assuming it is a laptop, from the picture, so can you launch into bios, and force the CPU's graphics over GPU? Then edit settings.

Comment: is it possible to force CPU graphics in BIOS?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you used the Startup Applications utility to add your command, according to this answer https://askubuntu.com/a/63413/55779 you should be able to:

1. Boot into a bootable Ubuntu USB stick.
2. Mount your HD and go to `/home/YOURUSER/.config/autostart` (or `/etc/xdg/autostart` if you set it up globally).
3. Edit the `.desktop` file for your custom command with a text editor of your choice.
4. Set `X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled` to `false`.
5. Save the file.

Reboot without the USB stick and assuming there are no other problems, your system should boot back up normally.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try this method out. Although, given the amount of problems I've faced so far in Ubuntu, I might switch to WSL instead.